# Is there a shortcut to close an View in Eclispe (an opposite of "show view")

Tags: eclipse

There is in eclipse default shortcut for showing the views, eg. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, <kbd>c</kbd> shows up the console.

But how can I close it?

I mean: I have minimized view with console on it, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to run, console shows up, and only way to close it is to click somewhere in editor - it is very inconveniently, couse cursor position is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run with your editor area maximised all the time, then, from any view, F12 will take you to the editor, and minimise any other views.

If you don't keep the editor maximised, then F12 will simply focus the editor without minimising any views.

In either case, Ctrl-M will toggle the editor between maximised and not.

Answer (score 0):

You can close the current part with `CTRL-W`or `CMD-W` on Mac... See the Keys preference page...

Answer (score 0):

Alt + _
and select Close from menu (arrow down, enter)